# RcppSimpleTensor: cannot use tensorFunction to compute multivariate object

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, rcpp

I want to use the tensorFunction in package RcppSimpleTensor (https://github.com/tlamadon/RcppSimpleTensor) to compute a 3 dimensional function like this one:

```
DGP <- function( x,y,z ) {
    return((x + y - 5)^2 + (z-5)^2)
}
```

I create 3 vectors of values for x,y and z:

```
xdata <- seq(0,10,length=10)
ydata <- seq(0,10,length=10)
zdata <- seq(0,5,length=15)
```

I define the tensorFunction:

```
library(RcppSimpleTensor)
RcppVals <- tensorFunction( R[i,j,k] ~ (X[i] + Y[j] - 5)^2 + (Z[k] - 5)^2 )
RcppArray <- RcppVals(xdata,ydata,zdata)
```

But running this function gives an error "Error in tmpfun(X, Y, Z, k, j, i) : expecting a single value"

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You may want to ask the author of that RcppSimpleTensor package.

Comment: yes, I filed a bug on github. it's the seq() in xdata. for example as.array(seq(0,10,le-10)) works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now fixed in the main branch of the code,

best,

t.